# mvc 4 assembly reference missing for Json.Encode

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, assembly-references

I am trying to call a `Json.Encode(...)` method in MVC 4 and I'm getting an error: `The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context.`

I've tried adding `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace, which has `Json` class, but this particular instance of `Json` class doesn't have `Encode` method.

What assembly am I missing here?

Here is my exact code:

```
{ url: '@Url.Action("DeleteDefinitionRule")', editData: 
    { companyCode: 'LO', definitionID:@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.DefinitionID)) } }
```

Comment: That's the question.  I know I'm supposed to be using something, but I don't know what.  I can't find it to save my life using google.

Comment: Looks like no such thing as Json.Encode

Comment: There are articles all over the web that say differently (such as this one: http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/basem-emara/2012/05/16/convert-a-c-object-to-javascript-in-mvc-razor).  However, none of them seem to address just how Json.Encode is referenced!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4072787/855421

Comment: It appears that this used to be located in System.Web.Helpers, but when I run object browser on that class, it's not in there anymore.  Was this moved to somewhere else?

Comment: Try this maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037895/where-can-i-find-system-web-helpers-system-web-webpages-and-system-web-razor

Answer (score 70, accepted):

1. References in solutions explorer > right click > Add reference
2. Under Assemblies > Framework, search for "System.Web.Helpers" Double click
3. System.Web.Helpers version 2.0.0.0 and click ok. Find the
4. System.Web.Helpers you've just added > right click it > properties.
5. **Change "Copy Local" from false, to true**

And now @Json.Encode should work.

**Update**

[image]

Comment: So I'm here again and again finding this answer helpful. Tanks

Comment: Also if you run into this issue when using MVC 5 RC (probably the same will go for MVC 5 RTM), this assembly package has been rebranded as Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers as per instructions here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2 and you can get it via Nuget UPDATE Actually this package is missing at the moment but it should reappear soon I guess.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem. But i'm wondering why we need to set "copy always". Why the namespace can't be simply resolved with a @using System.Web.Helpers?

Comment: This for some reason didn't work for me. I have the same version of the web.helpers dll and Razor won't find Json.Encode.

Answer (score 5):

To be clear, even after you add the correct reference to your project, you still have to add this line at the top of your Razor page:

```
@using System.Web.Helpers;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if you create a new empty web project, and try and move everything into Areas, it removes the Helpers library.  But if you create it as an internet project, they remain.  I created a new project as an internet project and everything works now.

Comment: That's not good enough for me^^. Really dont want to move everything in to a new project.

Comment: I had to add a hint path:       <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>