# html conditional compilation is turned off in MVC C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I wrote this function

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function saveDelivery() {
       alert("tttt")
       var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); //errror
       $.ajax({

           type: 'POST',

           url: '@Url.Action("SaveDelivery", "Business")',
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           data: JSON.serialize(model),
           success: function (result) {                                  
           },
           error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               alert(xhr.status);
               alert(thrownError);
          }
      });

  }
```

but there is error on

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

it says `conditional compilation is turned off`
How to slove this?

Comment: try this may be it will work 
var model = "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an Html Extension to output the script tags. This can help help with intellisense problems in Visual Studio also.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IHtmlString BeginScript(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
       return new HtmlString("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
    }

    public static IHtmlString EndScript(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        return new HtmlString("</script>");
    }
}
```

And then in your view:

```
@Html.BeginScript()

// JavaScript...

var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

// More JavaScript...

@Html.EndScript()
```

NOTE: You'll need to add the namespace of your extension class to the `<system.web.webPages.razor>` element in web.config (the one in the views folder)

Comment: +1: This seems like a pretty silly hack just to get around the studio's intellisense, but it absolutely does the trick.

Comment: @Demodave I've added some extra info. You need to put the methods in a static class and add the namespace to web.config.

Comment: @LeeGunn, Got it. Thax

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1. Do not care, you are sure about your code (it is warning)
2. Do something like this: `var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))`', but probably you will have to change it to: `var model = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))')`

Answer (score 0):

[mvc 4 assembly reference missing for Json.Encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682128/mvc-4-assembly-reference-missing-for-json-encode)

first add system.web.helper refrence 
then right click on this refrence property and change Copy Locaal=false to true
and run your code with json.Encode