# Json.Encode working in CS file but not in CSHTML

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my CS file I'm executing the following and it works as expected.

```
using System.Web.Helpers;
String json = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(null);
```

However, in my CSHTML file I'm executing the following, and here, I get an error about *Json* not being recognized in the context.

```
@{ Layout = null; }
@using TestService.ServiceReference;
@using System.Web.Helpers;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  var output3 = "! @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.MyArray))";
...
```

How can that be explained/remedied? Googling gave me nada, zero, ziltch...

## Edit

I've added *assemblies* tag to my CONFIG file as suggested but the error I'm getting is that it's an unknown to the configuration. This is what my (root) CONFIG looks like.

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, 
                  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
  ...
```

However, I've noticed that I do have the following in the CONFIG file instead. I'm guessing it's equivalent. Is it?

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: `@Html.Raw(System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(ViewBag.MyArray))` ?

Comment: Nope. Have tested that first of all (that's why I have *output3*, hehe). Same misbehavior.   :(

Comment: @KonradViltersten what is the data type for `ViewBag.MyArray`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682128/mvc-4-assembly-reference-missing-for-json-encode

Comment: @Kami It's a *Dictionary* but I hardly think that's the problem, since it's working on the server side but not on client (the *Json* class isn't found to begin with, so type errors are unlikely to be the cause).

Comment: Place complete reported error too. Thanks.

Comment: have you had a chance to correct your web.config per my comment below?  I am interested if you have this working yet (ie, the same error I got from the clean MVC4 project)

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi I did. It's in the question. :)

Comment: No, my meaning refers to Detailed Error. Or at least place output result in HTML or ... .

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi As I mentioned afore - it's all in the question. There's no other information accessible. If I had anything more, I'd sure post it. Bounty on a question means there's more to it than googling the error message.   :)   Besides, the issue has been resolved - please see the accepted reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to recreate your problem and also found a solution.  As to why this solution works, I cannot say, but here are the steps I followed.

1.From a fresh MVC 4 project (Basic), I created a View with the following mark up (note ReSharper 7 had no complaints)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    ViewBag.Array = new string[] {"apples", "oranges", "bananas"};
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var stuff = "! @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Array))";
    alert(stuff);
</script>

<h2>Index</h2>
```

2.Compiled and ran the application, received the following error:  `CS0103: The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context`.

3.Attempted to import namespace in View, added assembly to Views web.config, ensured proper reference in project.  None of these had an effect.

4.**The Solution**  Added the following lines (`<assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>`) to my web.config in the compilation section (the primary web.config, not the Views folder one)

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <!--Add the following.  Ensure compilation is not self closing,
          it was on mine-->    
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

5.Recompile and here is the resulting HTML page output sans error

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var stuff = "! ["apples","oranges","bananas"]";
    alert(stuff);
</script>

<h2>Index</h2>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: #4 is usually the reason. You let the IDE resolve it for you. I suspect @KonradViltersten did not

Comment: @KonradViltersten - the mapping rules that you found in your web.config were present in mine as well and I still got the error on the clean project.  Also, if you look closely at the config I posted, the <assemblies> are a sub element of the compilation XML element which is why I made the comment about the self-closing compilation tag, you will need to open that up : <compilation><assemblies></assemblies></compliation>

Comment: Awesome digging, bro. Error of high weirdness level...   :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're referencing `System.Web.Helpers` in your project and set "copy local" to **true**

Comment: I'm executing the code in CS file successfully **and** I have using in both CS and CSHTML file. Is that equivalent to *making sure to reference System.Web.Helpers* or is there anything more I can do? Also, please elaborate on *copy local = true*.

Comment: Look at BjarkeCKs answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682128/mvc-4-assembly-reference-missing-for-json-encode

Comment: Why? It doesn't address my issue at all. I'm not missing the assemblies. They're just not found on the client-side.