# How to access jsonstring in passed using viewdata in the view using jquery in c#, mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I send `json` string to the view using `viewdata` in my mvc , c# project.
this is in my `controller`

```
string getregionsforSearch = csv2json.returnJsonstringFull(getregionsPath);

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            ViewData["JsonRegionList"] = serializer.Serialize(getregionsforSearch);
```

now I want to retrieve it in my view inside

```
<script></script>
```

and `query` it.how can I do that.

Comment: Data passed from the controller to the view should be kept on the ViewModel it pains me to see why people use the ViewData store.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Json.Encode()` and `@Html.Raw()` as shown :-

```
<script>
     var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["JsonRegionList"]))
</script>
```

Comment: where to put `Json.Encode()` . in thre `controller` or in the `view`

Comment: @bill..as you can see i have written the code inside `script` so it is obvious that it will be in view inside `script` tags.

Comment: no what is the namespace for `Json.Encode` is it gives an error

Comment: its inside `System.Web.Helpers` namespace.

Comment: @bill...its inside `System.Web.Helpers` namespace

Comment: I import `System.Web.Helpers` to view and controller. it didn't work. it says  the namespace json does not exist in the current context. as hints it shows
`Netwonsoft.json` and another one.still exists the error

Comment: @bill..strange...try `var data = @Html.Raw(System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(ViewData["JsonRegionList"]))`

Comment: i try it too bro.nothing chaged

Comment: @bill...see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682128/mvc-4-assembly-reference-missing-for-json-encode) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726703/json-encode-working-in-cs-file-but-not-in-cshtml) ...SO post