# Convert view model data to json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I'm trying to convert my view model data to JSON, however, I can't seem to access `@Json.Encode`. I've added the `System.Web.Helpers` reference, but that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See this article at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682128/mvc-4-assembly-reference-missing-for-json-encode

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put this at the top of your view

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
```

And then you can do this

```
@Html.Raw(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.MyStuff))
```