# How to convert MVC ViewModel with multiple List properties to JSON for passing to Angularjs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Below is my MVC View model

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Role> LstRole { get; set; }
}
```

I need to convert this to JSON in controller action method which emits JSON to `angularjs` function

Below is my action method in controller

```
public string GetAllUsers()
{
    objUserView.LstRole = objUserManager.GetAllRoles();
    objUserView.FirstName = "Test";
    objUserView.LastName = "Test 1";
    objUserView.UserID = 1;
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objUserView.LstRole, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    });
}
```

When I run this action method it gives below error

> Self referencing loop detected for property 'Role' with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Role_EE4037A57E80F8AE5D8E070E7325B72D7AE3916C26C19F53CB6F5084B2181234'. Path '$values`enter code here`[1].UserMasters.$values[0]'.

Please assist

Comment: Whats the `Role` model?

Comment: In jsonSerializesettings did you try :  'ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize'  OR 'PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects'

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)

Comment: You should probably make a RoleViewModel as well, since that is (most likely) referencing a list of Users, which in turn is referencing Role. Also, returning a list of users attached to a role may be a potential security risk.

Answer (score 1):

Add this `ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` to JsonSerializerSettings

like below

```
public string GetAllUsers()
{
    objUserView.LstRole = objUserManager.GetAllRoles();
    objUserView.FirstName = "Test";
    objUserView.LastName = "Test 1";
    objUserView.UserID = 1;
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objUserView.LstRole, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Did you try converting it on the view? Something like that may help: [Convert view model data to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217067/convert-view-model-data-to-json)