# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL textarea rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to render simple html in textarea as if it is inline html case.
This is what i tried-

**simple html-**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Header</h4>
        <div style="color:green">This is the text here with the imframe template </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As it is shown here, It is saved in database also.
At the time of rendering it into textarea , My console inspector shows me error while rendering it in textarea- `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

I know this has to do something with illegal characters. But How do I proceed?

**jQuery-**

```
 $('#temphtmlcode').val("@Html.Raw(Model.Template)");
```

Here `Model.Template` is coming from database in above html manner-

**My textarea-**

```
 <textarea style="height: 215px; width: 500px;" id="temphtmlcode"></textarea>
```

This textarea doesn't contain html and shows unexpected error.
Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$('#temphtmlcode').val("@Html.Raw(Model.Template)");
```

Try

```
$('#temphtmlcode').val("@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Template))");
```

Comment: Json is not recognized by the view.

Comment: @AakankshaSingh..sorry i didn't get you??

Comment: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Template), Here `Json doesn't exist in the current context` problem

Comment: @AakankshaSingh...see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682128/mvc-4-assembly-reference-missing-for-json-encode